# Why does AutoCAD Map 3D only display last/current line when drawing a polygon?

Tags: drawing, polygon, autocad

When I'm trying to digitize a new industry model feature by drawing a polygon, AutoCAD Map 3D shows only the last/current line, but not formerly draw line sections of the polygon, until the polygon is closed. Once it is closed, then entire polygon is displayed. How can this issue be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corresponding AutoCAD layer (not industry model layer), in which the polygon was drawn, was invisible. Displaying the AutoCAD layer solved this issue, because the polygon belongs to the AutoCAD layer as long as it is not finished and will only be displayed as feature of the industry model layer once it has been completed.